# How to convert test log file to json in a prescribed way

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a log file which is below.trying to take first server details `192.168.1.1` and check when it is connected and disconnected.then go to second server `192.168.1.2` details and check when it is connected and disconnected. Like way need to determine the connection time and disconnected time of all servers

```
str_ = '''Jan 23 2016 11:30:08AM - ssh 22 192.168.1.1 connected
Jan 23 2016 12:04:56AM - ssh 22 192.168.1.2 connected
Jan 23 2016 2:18:32PM - ssh 22 192.168.1.2 disconnected 
Jan 23 2016 5:16:09PM - un x Dos attack from 201.10.0.4
Jan 23 2016 10:43:44PM - ssh 22 192.168.1.1 disconnected
Feb 1 2016  1:40:28AM - ssh 22 192.168.1.1 connected
Feb 1 2016  2:21:52AM - un x Dos attack from 201.168.123.1
Mar 29 2016 2:13:07PM - ssh 22 192.168.1.1 disconnected'''
```

How to convert my log file in to json

My Expected out

`{1:{192.168.1.1:[(connected,Jan 23 2016 11:30:08AM),(disconnected,Jan 23 2016 10:43:44PM)]},
 2:{192.168.1.2:[(connected,Jan 23 2016 12:04:56AM),(disconnected,Jan 23 2016 2:18:32PM)]},
 3:{192.168.1.1:[(connected,Feb 1 2016  1:40:28AM),(disconnected,Mar 29 2016 2:13:07PM )]},
 4:{Dos:[201.10.0.4,201.168.123.1]}}`

My Pseudo code

```
import json
import re
i = 1
result = {}
with open('test.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        r = line.split('')
        #result[i] = {}
        i += 1 
print(result) 
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(result, fp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why do you need dict keyed by entry numbers `{1: xxx, 2: yyy, 3: zzz}`? I'll advise using just a list instead - `[xxx, yyy, zzz]`. You can get an entry by index and so on. Technically json can't use numbers as keys.
2. There is no logic to group connected and disconnected events in your pseudocode.
3. Some lines from log don't has connect/disconnect info, so you need some logic for it too.
4. `lines = f.readlines(); for line in lines:` may eat lots of memory for large log files, just use `for lines in f:`

So, I think you need something like:

```
import json
import re

result = []
opened = {}

with open('test.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        date, rest = line.split(' - ', 1)
        rest, last = rest.strip().rsplit(' ', 1)
        ip = rest.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
        if last  == 'connected':
            entry = {ip: [(last, date)]}
            opened[ip] = entry
            result.append(entry)
        elif last == 'disconnected':
            opened[ip][ip].append((last, date))
            del opened[ip]

print(result) 
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(result, fp)
```

It works for your sample, but needs more error checking for other logs

Comment: why you delete del opened[ip],

Comment: ```opened``` - is the temporary storage for sessions that weren't disconnected. After we add disconnected event we don't need to remember the session. All data stored in ```result```